# Is it possible to retrieve Windows monitor layout information in .NET?

Tags: .net, windows, multiple-monitors

I'm wondering if it's possible to extract Windows monitor layout information programmatically in .NET.  At a minimum, the information I'm interested in is the screen resolution and position in some coordinate space.  Model and physical dimensions would be useful.  The ability to write back to the layout would be awesome.

[image]

Comment: Do you really want to know the answer to this, or are you just showing off your monitors!

Comment: I admit a little bit from column 'B'... :-P

I intend to use imagemagick to automatically scale, shift, and 'kern' an image so a background can be applied to a multi-monitor desktop and look seamless across monitor bezels.

Comment: Multi-monitor desktop backgrounds can be painful, I've been there. For testing your imaging routines, I recommend that you move one of the monitors to a negative y start position (look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6388667/520044) for example screenshot of a monitor setup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [AllScreens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens.aspx) property of the [Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx) class, that should give you at least a starting point regarding your multiple monitor setup. I don't know if you can use it to manipulate values though.

Comment: Screen.AllScreens contains all the layout information I was hoping for.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like the system configuration can be manipulated through the object.