# MouseWheel handler doesn't handle MouseEvent with my .NET 2 form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c++-cli, mousewheel

I'd like to be an early adopter of using the mouse wheel to scroll my document and although the Forms designer doesn't publish the `onMouseWheel` property I have configured the handler programmatically in my ctor just after `InitializeComponent();`- 'cos I'm not so bold as to mess with that.

```
Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    this->MouseWheel += gcnew MouseEventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_MouseWheel);
    //stuff
}
```

I'm trapping there okay but I can't trap in the handler itself. Anyone else get this problem? I'm using a Synaptics touchpad and .NET 2.0 on VS2008 (for backwards compatibility). The cursor changes to the rolling wheen but no further action occurs on screen.

Answers in C# are equally appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mouse Wheel Event (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479284/mouse-wheel-event-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be bad form to add a belated comment to [Mouse Wheel Event (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479284/mouse-wheel-event-c/479358#479358) ? There lies my answer, although in this case it was the textbos which had taken the focus from the Form and captured its mousewheel event.

I suppose I shouldn't have asked the original question, maybe it will help others not have to.