# c# RichTextBox - scrolling with hidden ScrollBar

Tags: c#, scrollbar, richtextbox

I have RichTextBox control with hidden both Scrollbars. When they are hidden I can't scroll text with mouse, I can only use PgUp and PgDown keys to move the text.

But I want to scroll with mouse when ScrollBars are disabled, is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Try something like this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479284/mouse-wheel-event-c

This should helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    richTextBox1.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(richTextBox_MouseWheel);

}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


}
void richTextBox_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
         MessageBox.Show(e.Delta.ToString());
         // use this value to scroll

        }
```